# Comparing order of $\ker f$ and $\ker\tilde{f}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism, diagram-chasing

Let $A$,$B$ be abelian groups. Let $f: A\to B$ be group homomorphism.

Let $C\subset A$ and $D\subset B$ be subgroups of $A$ and $B$.

Let $C\subset D$.
There is a canonical map $\tilde{f}: A/C \to B/D,x \bmod C \mapsto x \bmod D$.

I want to prove $\#\ker\tilde{f}\le \#\ker f$.

My try: Since $\ker\tilde{f}=\dfrac{\ker f}{C \cap \ker f}\#\ker\tilde{f}\le \#\ker f$.

However, I have some concerns about this apparent consideration. The reason is that, in the following diagram, it cannot generally be said that $h$ is surjective. Reflecting on this, I wonder if there is an error somewhere in my consideration. That's why I am asking this question here. I would appreciate your help.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\ker f@>>>A @>{f}>> B\\
@V{h}VV @VVV@VVV\\
\ker{\tilde{f}}@>>>A/C @>{\tilde{f}}>> B/D
\end{CD}

Comment: \mod or \pmod, pick one, \text'ing it doesn't typeset right

Comment: "Let $C\subset D$" doesn't make sense. You probably mean $f(C)\subset D$.

Comment: The kernel of $\tilde{f}$ is not equal to $\ker(f)/(C\cap \ker(f))$, because the two "live" in different groups. $\ker(\tilde{f})$ is a subgroup of $A/C$, and $\ker(f)/(C\cap\ker(f))$ is a subgroup of $A/(C\cap\ker f)$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Oh, you're correct. Thank you. In general, is it difficult to judge which is bigger, $kerf$ or $ker\tilde{f}$ ?What in my mind is the case of $C=A[2]=\{a\in A\mid 2a=0\},D=B[2]$.

Comment: `\ker f` produces $\ker f$. Please review the edits I made to your post so you can typeset correctly in the (immediate) future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume "Let $C\subset D$" means "Let $f(C)\subseteq D$." (Examples can be done with proper inclusion).

As written, the desired inequality need not hold. Let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$.

Take $A=C_{4}$, $B=C_2$, $f$ the nontrivial map, $C$ the trivial subgroup, $D=B$. Then $\ker f$ has two elements and $\ker\tilde{f}$ has four elements. So here the kernel of $\tilde{f}$ is larger.

Now Take $A=C_4$, $B=C_2$, $f$ the nontrivial map, $C$ the kernel of $f$, $D$ the trivial subgroup. Now the kernel of $\tilde{f}$ has one element and that of $f$ has two, do here $\ker f$ is larger.

Finally take $C$ and $D$ trivial. Then $\ker f=\ker\tilde{f}$.

So they can be equal, or either one can be larger than the other.

Comment: Thank you very much for 3 examples. What do you think about the case $C=A[2]$, $D=B[2]$ ?

Comment: @Pont I think you should learn to ask what you really want to ask, and not use comments to try to get answers to different questions. In short, you should not keep misusing the site.